# test an onlyowner modifer function with "to.be.revertedWith()",but it seems that it dosen't work

Tags: javascript, testing

my smart contract is 'Ownable', and the withdraw() function has an onlyowner modifer. Now I'm going to test if a not owner account could call the withdraw function successfully, I used revertedWith() to test it, but it seems that it dosen't catch the reverted message;

**here is a part of contract code**

```
contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
  
    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

}
```

**here is the testcase**

```
    it("Should not be withdrawed by notowner", async function () {
      const { myToken, mintPrice, mintTokenNumber, owner, addr1 } =
        await loadFixture(deployTokenFixture);

      expect(await myToken.connect(addr1).withdraw()).to.be.revertedWith(
        "Ownable: caller is not the owner"
      );
    });
```

**this is error information**

```
 1 failing

  1) MyToken contract
       Withdraw
         Should not be withdrawed by notowner:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Ownable: caller is not the owner'
    at MyToken._checkOwner (@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:51)
    at MyToken.onlyOwner (@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:36)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1840:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:517:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1532:18)
```

where is the wrong? how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Does your onlyowner modifier code have a revert function?

example

```
modifier onlyOwner {
           if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert NotOwner();
        _;
    }
```